Correct usage of "I'd rather"
Is this sentence grammatically correct, and if it is, does it sound good or is there a more natural sounding way to say this? (Than using "I'd rather"?)

I'd rather you were a living sinner than a dead saint.


It sounds fine to me, along with such as "I'd rather die on my feet than live on my knees."

I think Americans tend to use "I'd prefer" rather than "I'd rather" when talking about other people, but that may just be a personal bias.

To get a useful answer, please edit to tell a bit more about what concerns you. It's fine, but that's not a great answer.

@Barmar Really? It doesn't seem like a regional distinction to me; if anything "I'd rather" seems more Tom-Sawyer-Americana than "I'd prefer." (C.f. "If I had my druthers")

@AndyBonner That's going back to the 19th century, styles have changed significantly. "If I had my druthers" persists from then, but it doesn't mean people would say "I'd rather" in the same situation.

@Barmar Hm, I'd still rather say "rather" when given the choice (of course, nGrams doesn't parse by region, but like I say I'm not aware of any regionality). And of course the sentence structure matters: "I'd prefer chocolate" is leaner than "I'd rather have chocolate," but "I'd prefer you to be on time" is clunkier than "I'd rather you were on time."

@AndyBonner Yes, there are many common uses of "rather". But in the OP's example, I'd prefer "prefer".
